# Creating a component library with Next.js 13 - Modifications in next.config.js and package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, build

I'm working on creating a component library based on Next.js 13, and I would like to know if it's possible to achieve this. If so, I would appreciate guidance on the necessary modifications in the next.config.js and package.json files.

My goal is to have a file, app/index.tsx, that exports all my components from the library.

Any help or advice on the following questions would be greatly appreciated:

1- Is it possible to create a component library using Next.js 13? Are there any specific considerations or limitations I should be aware of?

2- What modifications should I make in the next.config.js file to ensure the successful creation of the component library? Specifically, what configuration options or settings are relevant for building a library?

3- In my package.json file, what changes should I make to properly configure the library? How can I set up the build process to export all my components from the app/index.tsx file?

I'm looking forward to any insights or recommendations that can help me create a component library using Next.js 13. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I tried to create a component library based on an existing React library that I was already publishing on npm. I started by retrieving the code of the React library and made some modifications to adapt it for Next.js. Specifically, I added a next.config.js file to configure Next.js, and I made changes to the package.json file, including using next build for the build process.

My expectation was that after these modifications, I would be able to successfully build the library using Next.js and export it as a component library that can be published on npm. I was expecting to have a properly built library with all the necessary files and configurations in place.

However, I encountered some issues and observed that the expected index.js file was missing from the out directory after running the next build command. This raised concerns about whether I am following the correct approach and whether I am missing any additional configurations or modifications.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly create a component library with Next.js 13 and ensure the successful build and export process.

Comment: NextJS is usually used to build Applications and not libraries. If you want to build a component library, may I suggest taking a look at Daisy UI (https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui). Maybe some inspiration can be found here.